# Visual Studio 2017 msbuild different to dotnet client tools

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, teamcity

I have a .NET Core 2.0 project that builds and runs xunit tests fine in Visual Studio 2017. We use Team City for our CI builds but it uses the build runner tools .NET CLI (dotnet).

We recently had some changes that were fine in Visual Studio but when our Team City process attempted to run the unit tests with the command `dotnet test` some of the tests failed.

I then reproduced this locally by running `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` on the command line.

We use NCrunch to monitor live code changes and it too did not have a problem executing the unit tests.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio use the .NET CLI (dotnet) build tools for .NET Core applications to avoid this in difference between msbuild and dotnet in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio carries a .NET Framework build of MSBuild that has slight differences to the .NET Core version of MSBuild (primarily some additional features that other project types use as well as running on .NET Framework instead of .NET Core).

This version of MSBuild loads the build tasks and targets based on the presence and content of a global.json file in the project directory hierarchy as well as prerelease settings inside VS.

The .NET Core CLI always loads the targets/tasks from it contains.

In theory, any build issues arising from these differences should be worked around by making targets and tasks compatible with both versions based on variables like `$(MSBuildRuntimeType)` (values `Core`, `Mono` or `Full`).

Comment: I don't have a global.json file for my project or solution, the project properties in VS2017 have the target framework set to .NET Core 2.0. I am wondering if it would be best to try and change team city to use msbuild now that it supports building .NET Core?

Comment: That would depend on the error you are getting.. But since you didn't provide details about this in the question i can't give you any better advice

Comment: The error was to do we using .resx files with binary content (which you can do in .NET framework but I've since found out that this is not supported yet in .NET Core). This only showed itself when I ran dotnet test on the command line. When I built and tested inside Visual Studio, I did not have any errors related to using the advanced features in resource files.

Comment: That is a known problem of the build system since MSBuild uses .net framework 
 components (actually winforms parts) to serialize the resources. this may change for .net core 3.0. see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/2272). You can also build using MSBuild.exe and use `dotnet test --no-build` or use `msbulid /t:VSTest` instead of `dotnet test`